# How to change Excel format when thousand and decimal seperator is changed

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetgear

I have an option allowing user to select thousand seperator and decimal seperator in my windows application.How can i change the worksheet-> Cell's Number format based on selected seperators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to specify the thousands separator and decimal separator used by a workbook in SpreadsheetGear is indirectly--by passing in a particular [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.CultureInfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object when you initially create/open the workbook via Factory.[GetWorkbook](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Factory~GetWorkbook.html)(...) or Factory.[GetWorkookSet](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Factory~GetWorkbookSet.html)(...).  SpreadsheetGear uses the various options for that CultureInfo object, such as CultureInfo.NumberFormat.[NumberGroupSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0xh94xt(v=vs.110).aspx) / [NumberDecimalSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b74zyt45(v=vs.110).aspx), to format cells in the workbook.

Problem is, you cannot tweak a workbook's CultureInfo object's individual properties to use different formatting options nor can you "hot swap" one overall CultureInfo object for another while a workbook is opened.

So the only way to change things like the thousands and decimal separator characters is to:

1. Close any currently-open workbooks using the "old" separator characters.
2. Re-open or re-create these workbooks, specifying some other [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.CultureInfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object into Factory.[GetWorkbook](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Factory~GetWorkbook.html)(...) or Factory.[GetWorkookSet](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Factory~GetWorkbookSet.html)(...) that uses the desired thousand or decimal separator characters.

As a result, you may need to alter your application to specify a particular region instead of individual separator characters, i.e., your user provides a region which you can use to get a particular CultureInfo object via the CultureInfo.[GetCultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540(v=vs.110).aspx)(*name*) method, where *name* might be "en-US", "en-GB", "de-DE", "hi-IN", etc.  If it helps, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(VS.71).aspx) is one page that lists a number of predefined CultureInfo codes.

Comment: Thank you Tim...!!! I thought of changing only the format.but you gave me various options to implement this.I will follow this.